# Subclass INObject?

Tags: ios12, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

Can one subclass `INObject`?

I ask because I have an Intents Handler Extension for Siri Shortcuts. I attempted to create a subclass for `INObject` because I want to add an extra property. Seems like it works just fine here.

However, I also have an Intents Handler UI Extension. When my response object gets to this point, I have a handle on the `INObject` and its identifier and display string. But, when I try to cast it to my custom `INObject` sublcassed type, the result is nil and therefore I cannot access my custom property.

Does anyone know how to pass custom properties from the Intents Extension to the Intents UI Extension using the custom `INObject`?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet.

Comment: @ShivaReddy - Just use the userInfo property in NSUserActivity and set the userActivity for INIntentResponse. Worked well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Engineering got back to me that this is not supported.